# How to update only specific JSON object properties with PUT router, and the other remain the same?

Tags: node.js, json, express, routes

```
router.put('/books/:id',(req,res)=>{
    const {id}=req.params;
    const {
        isbn,
        title,
        subtitle,
        author,
        published,
        publisher,
        pages,
        description,
        website     
    }=req.body;

    booksDirectory.forEach((book,index)=>{
        if(book.isbn===id){
            booksDirectory[index]={
                isbn:`${id}`,// if isbn is not provided in req body, book doesnt exist
                title,
                subtitle,
                author,
                published,
                publisher,
                pages,
                description,
                website 
            };
        }
      
    });
   res.send(`The book with ID ${id} has been updated!`)
  
})
```

Im trying to update a book inside a books object by providing the book info in the PUT request body.
If i provide only one property, the object will have only that one property, and the rest of the properties will not exist when i try to get that book.
I want the object properties to be updated only with the properties provided, and the remaining properties to stay the same(if new ones are not provided).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update an object from array of objects of books you need to do this:

```
const {id}=req.params;
    const {
        isbn,
        title,
        subtitle,
        author,
        published,
        publisher,
        pages,
        description,
        website     
    }=req.body;

bookDict.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    if(element.isbn==isbn){
            if(title){
                element.title=title;
            }
            if(subtitle){
                element.subtitle=subtitle;
            }
            if(author){
                element.author=author;
            }
            if(published){
                element.published=published;
            }
            if(publisher){
                element.publisher=publisher;
            }
            if(pages){
                element.pages=pages
            }
            if(description){
                element.description=description;
            }
            if(website){
                element.website=website;
            }
        }
});
```

and make sure you bookDict should follow the structure below:

```
var bookDict = [
    {
        "isbn": 1,
        "title": "Book1",
        "subtitle": "book1",
        "author": "Ali",
        "published": "Ali",
        "publisher": "Ali",
        "pages": "100",
        "description": "Book",
        "website": "www.book.com"  
    },
    {
        "isbn": 2,
        "title": "Book1",
        "subtitle": "book1",
        "author": "Ali",
        "published": "Ali",
        "publisher": "Ali",
        "pages": "100",
        "description": "Book",
        "website": "www.book.com" 
    },
    {
        "isbn": 3,
        "title": "Book1",
        "subtitle": "book1",
        "author": "Ali",
        "published": "Ali",
        "publisher": "Ali",
        "pages": "100",
        "description": "Book",
        "website": "www.book.com" 
    }
];
```

and test the results by consoling the bookDict:

```
bookDict.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    console.log(element.title)
});
```

Comment: Thanks.I modified the code a bit and it works.I guess i needed to check if a property in the req body exists and only then assign it to the book.

Comment: Mention not. 
Kindly if you find my answer helpful in anyway then approve it pls!